# Failed to convert javascript to typescript, giving errors?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I write one javascript function. Then I convert it to typescript. When I convert I am getting 3 errors. I can't do this fix. Please anyone help me.

```
const countryData = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Afghanistan',
        isoAlpha2: 'AF',
        isoAlpha3: 'AFG',
        isoNumeric: 4,
        currency: {
            code: 'AFN',
            name: 'Afghani',
            symbol: '؋'
        },
        flag: "flasg",
        callingCodes: ['+93'],
        languages: ['pus'],
        emoji: ''
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Albania',
        isoAlpha2: 'AL',
        isoAlpha3: 'ALB',
        isoNumeric: 8,
        currency: {
            code: 'ALL',
            name: 'Lek',
            symbol: 'L'
        },
        flag: "flasg",
        callingCodes: ['+355'],
        languages: ['sqi'],
        emoji: ''
    }
]

export interface CountryDataTypes {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    isoAlpha2: string;
    isoAlpha3: string;
    isoNumeric: number;
    currency: {
        code: string;
        name: string;
        symbol: string | boolean;
    }
    flag: string;
    callingCodes: string[];
    languages: string[];
    emoji: string;
}
interface Props {
    name?: string;
    countryCode?: string;
    callingCode?: string;
    currencyName?: string;
    currencyCode?: string;
    currencySymbol?: string;
    isoNumeric?: number;
}

export function lookup(data: Props): CountryDataTypes {
    const fields = Object.entries(data)
    const result = countryData.find((d) => { // Error 1
        for (var key in fields) {
            return d[fields[key][0]] === fields[key][1] //Error 2
        }
    })
    return result as CountryDataTypes || {} as CountryDataTypes;
}
```

Here is live link- [click here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBKCuYoCcCeARAhlTMC8MA2gFAxkwDep5NAlgCYBcMAjADTU1liYC2ApswDkAQQBmAcwAWmMLWiyhHLuXkgRAGwAOMgEzCRAMSWcuazTswBmA4YDiJlWTUA5eAOS1gzACzKnwPDIyPxgwKjMVE5coPSCMKKGLo7R5DwCBpIycimpMBCovABGIBrCgNBgQqY0AL7+KmIamBLMAESNmBASrfUxmBoatGASAMIgcRDMhEIA1ACcVkIAur00TcPwzfyTREJa8BDLq+T8vCAAVrTCgDwbgGe714DXu1W1vVFODMy6x9x88aIaRVktEwuTMEHU2j0BgAMqC6OCLDIbAkRNCAEJw1TgtweLzMAAc3zgQRCYQilGqAXGf1RsKJNHSf2h-AA1piVAViqVhLDKWQ6nyYB0WjB2k0uj1BcB+oNhmMJlNZlYAKzKo6C9YSTYSbaKiAAR1o6uipwuVwSd2ugEfd57kGrEJbEYj8AAeWhAyFgQyg-GQYkwwH4MDGiBQGGwmAAKqgtNsKXQmDAwO4ir6ANymRnMaCeYYZ+EQyz6fIoIYSfNYwtI7OlvOmVzuX14pMp9OmQLBULhSJS6k13PlwVZksDiscwolMojsswAA+MBKpX4sjHMHtNGF-bLq+lAzL8t10+GhCWq812sPObLJ9XpsuW7r9u9vv9gZgAAVkCAtBB42lfgA-A+g40AgSBoAeQFHiB5C7rKozUlBV51qBJJdqgLiAcBO5oWSkHYe2uHhAAyhOpRIbWMHONijaeMAUHJsUbb2s6boerAYiIMAUC0OAMAaCAIAsvAWgABT0BGzCft+EAAJTMCG4Hhjg0axr+bxkKAkAcbQ-AaPQv4EAA8kU5z8NxAB0oSlts4kRrJ7bgNAMAhBA8AaLABBgWGWA4BZYhDPQonibJ+AAHx-g0HowKJABumDIDALL8KgMBDEKun6XJkWpCEUBBGAMD0IQAV6QZhDJagSyEAADEsSz4HgBClVlFUpdVLCOtE652g5NB5QVLnbO5sCdMGIChmgvlRjGcazvOFA1DAY2KT5EaqdsGY9UAA)

Here I am write function for filtering country data. It works in javascript fine. But when I convert it to typescript then it gives me errors.

> //Additional-
> Error 1-
> Not all code paths return a value.
> Error 2-
> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ id: number; name: string; isoAlpha2: string; isoAlpha3: string; isoNumeric: number; currency: { code: string; name: string; symbol: string; }; flag: string; callingCodes: string[]; languages: string[]; emoji: string; }'.
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ id: number; name: string; isoAlpha2: string; isoAlpha3: string; isoNumeric: number; currency: { code: string; name: string; symbol: string; }; flag: string; callingCodes: string[]; languages: string[]; emoji: string; }'.

Comment: When asking a question that involves error messages of some sort, you **must** include the exact errors in the question.

Comment: Okay. I am doing that. But if you click the link then you can see the error and online editor from typescript official site.

Comment: Please help to, please.

Comment: Your `lookup` function doesn't make any sense. You use `Object.entries` just to use `for..in` loop later, which gives your keys, but not that keys that you wanted. And you create a loop just to leave immediately. You get ts errors because typescript helps you find mistakes that you've made. Make this function work and ts will work as well

Comment: In javascript, it works perfectly.

Comment: @konrad, Actually I want to find by any filed. if user sent `name` then search by `name`. If user sent `isoAlpha2` then find by `isoAlpha2`. If user sent `name` and `isoAlpha2` together then find by this two field. If user sent three fields then it should filter by that 3 fields. Here I do not know which field I use for filtering.

Comment: Can you fix my function please. I am not getting any idea.

Comment: Your loop ends after one iteration, it will never handle more than one field

Comment: Also `for...in` on an array yields indexs `0, 1, 2, 3` not field names. `for...of` would make more sense

Comment: Also, what is `isoNumeric[0]`? Looks like a potential error to me

Comment: If user sent isoNumeric then it need to find by isoNumeric

Comment: Here, Actually, I don't know what field should be used for filter. It can be `name, or isoAlpha2, or isoAlpha3, or isoNumeric or any field`. Just I need to filter by which field sent by user.

Comment: I think, You can understand now. If need, please rewrite the function.

Answer (score 0):

Error 1 is because `fields` maybe empty and thus for loop will never loop thus your arrow function will never return anything. just add a return statement after the for loop to return some default value or throw an error.

Error 2 is because typeof `fields[key][0]` is `string`, you can't use an abitrary `string` value to index `d`, but only strings matches one of `d`'s property names. if you are sure that `fields[key][0]` is a valid property name of `d`, you can make a cast to tell the compiler: `d[fields[key][0] as keyof(typeof d)]`. (But I don't think that's the case in your scenario and I doubt you have a logical bug here).

And you for loop could be simplified as:

```
        for (const [key, value] of fields) {
            return d[key as keyof(typeof d)] === value;
        }
```

Logically `key` would be `'name' | 'countryCode' | 'callingCode' | 'currencyName' | 'currencyCode' | 'currencySymbol' | 'isoNumeric'`. Use these values to index `d` doesn't make much sense, 'cause only `name` is available on `d`. Thus `key`'s type is not `keyof(typeof d)`, and we are lying to the compiler.